# Ler xml em Java

Tags: java, xml

Eu estou usando um programa chamado Tiled(TileMap) para gerar um mapa e quero fazer  leitura desses números.

O xml é assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" tiledversion="1.0.2" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="42" height="34" tilewidth="16" tileheight="16" nextobjectid="8">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="tileset" tilewidth="16" tileheight="16" tilecount="924" columns="33">
  <image source="tileset.png" trans="003bff" width="528" height="448"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="background" width="42" height="34">
  <data encoding="csv"> // Apos isso
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,
763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763,763
</data>
 </layer>
```

Só que eu não encontrei nenhuma maneira que eu possa fazer isso, sem copiar para um outro arquivo.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: O que você quer fazer com esses dados? Você pode usar o `JSoup` pra isso. Posso fazer um exemplo se você disser exatamente o que quer extrair daí.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [jackson-xml-dataformat](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml)

Pra isso basta adicionar a dependência no seu pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Você pode definir os beans de acordo com a estrutura do seu XML:

tag **data**

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="data")
public class XmlData {

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String encoding;

  @JacksonXmlText
  private String value;

  public String getEncoding() {
    return encoding;
  }

  public void setEncoding(String encoding) {
    this.encoding = encoding;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

 }
```

tag **layer**

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "layer")
public class XmlLayer {

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String name;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String width;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String height;

  @JacksonXmlProperty
  private XmlData data;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getWidth() {
    return width;
  }

  public void setWidth(String width) {
    this.width = width;
  }

  public String getHeight() {
    return height;
  }

  public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
  }

  public XmlData getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(XmlData data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

}
```

tag **image**

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "image")
public class XmlImage {

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String source;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String trans;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String width;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String height;

  public String getSource() {
    return source;
  }

  public void setSource(String source) {
    this.source = source;
  }

  public String getTrans() {
    return trans;
  }

  public void setTrans(String trans) {
    this.trans = trans;
  }

  public String getWidth() {
    return width;
  }

  public void setWidth(String width) {
    this.width = width;
  }

  public String getHeight() {
    return height;
  }

  public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
  }

}
```

tag **tileset**

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "tileset")
public class XmlTileSet {

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "firstgid")
  private String firstGid;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "name")
  private String name;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "tilewidth")
  private String tileWidth;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "tileheight")
  private String tileHeight;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "tilecount")
  private String tileCount;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "columns")
  private String columns;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private XmlImage image;

  public String getFirstGid() {
    return firstGid;
  }

  public void setFirstGid(String firstGid) {
    this.firstGid = firstGid;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getTileWidth() {
    return tileWidth;
  }

  public void setTileWidth(String tileWidth) {
    this.tileWidth = tileWidth;
  }

  public String getTileHeight() {
    return tileHeight;
  }

  public void setTileHeight(String tileHeight) {
    this.tileHeight = tileHeight;
  }

  public String getTileCount() {
    return tileCount;
  }

  public void setTileCount(String tileCount) {
    this.tileCount = tileCount;
  }

  public String getColumns() {
    return columns;
  }

  public void setColumns(String columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
  }

  public XmlImage getImage() {
    return image;
  }

  public void setImage(XmlImage image) {
    this.image = image;
  }

}
```

tag **map**

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "map")
public class XmlMap {

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "version")
  private String version;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "tiledversion")
  private String tiledVersion;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "orientation")
  private String orientation;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "renderorder")
  private String renderOrder;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String width;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  private String height;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "tilewidth")
  private String tileWidth;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "tileheight")
  private String tileHeight;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "nextobjectid")
  private String nextObjectId;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "tileset")
  private XmlTileSet xmlTileSet;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "layer")
  private XmlLayer xmlLayer;

  public String getVersion() {
    return version;
  }

  public void setVersion(String version) {
    this.version = version;
  }

  public String getTiledVersion() {
    return tiledVersion;
  }

  public void setTiledVersion(String tiledVersion) {
    this.tiledVersion = tiledVersion;
  }

  public String getOrientation() {
    return orientation;
  }

  public void setOrientation(String orientation) {
    this.orientation = orientation;
  }

  public String getRenderOrder() {
    return renderOrder;
  }

  public void setRenderOrder(String renderOrder) {
    this.renderOrder = renderOrder;
  }

  public String getWidth() {
    return width;
  }

  public void setWidth(String width) {
    this.width = width;
  }

  public String getHeight() {
    return height;
  }

  public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
  }

  public String getTileWidth() {
    return tileWidth;
  }

  public void setTileWidth(String tileWidth) {
    this.tileWidth = tileWidth;
  }

  public String getTileHeight() {
    return tileHeight;
  }

  public void setTileHeight(String tileHeight) {
    this.tileHeight = tileHeight;
  }

  public String getNextObjectId() {
    return nextObjectId;
  }

  public void setNextObjectId(String nextObjectId) {
    this.nextObjectId = nextObjectId;
  }

  public XmlTileSet getXmlTileSet() {
    return xmlTileSet;
  }

  public void setXmlTileSet(XmlTileSet xmlTileSet) {
    this.xmlTileSet = xmlTileSet;
  }

  public XmlLayer getXmlLayer() {
    return xmlLayer;
  }

  public void setXmlLayer(XmlLayer xmlLayer) {
    this.xmlLayer = xmlLayer;
  }

}
```

Lendo o xml:

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
XmlMap data = mapper.readValue(new File("/direrotio/arquivo.xml"), XmlMap.class);
System.out.println(data.getXmlLayer().getData().getValue());
```

o input do método readValue pode ser byte array, InputStream e etc, só dar uma olhada na documentação.